# Drupal 7 - hook_node_insert is being ignored and out of memory error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have hook_node_insert in my module. It worked before but it is not working anymore. The only clue I have, is that when I (re)enable modules, then it gives me out of memory fatal error. After that, it shows that all modules, which I enabled are enabled and usually everything works after this out of memory error. What do you think, is this error causing the problem or not? And in any case, what are the solutions? (My hostgator shared hosting plan doesn't allow me to increase memory limits)

Comment: If you disable a certain number of modules, does the out of memory error go away? Drupal does require a lot of memory if you have a lot of modules during certain operations. We can't speculate about why your hook doesn't work without the module code, though.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue, & having difficulty finding any info about it.

Comment: * By "same issue", I mean that hook_node_insert used to get triggered normally, now it doesn't, but only for certain content types. Not having the out-of-memory error issue.

Comment: Found this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56779/my-hooks-are-not-invoked-by-drupal

Answer (score 0):

You need to call somewhere node_save() explicitly.

```
node_save($node)
```

Comment: Add it where? Adding it inside of hook_node_insert won't do anything if hook_node_insert is never getting called. Or perhaps I misunderstood?